# Warning mysql_fetch_array when I use MATCH, AGAINST in PHP/mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error **Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource**

when I changed my code to this

```
$term = $_POST["term"];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM planet1 WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$term')");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
echo $row['id'],'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when there is an error during the execution of the SQL query :

- [`mysql_query()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_query) returns `false`
- and that's not a resource as [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) expects.

You should try calling [**`mysql_error()`**](http://www.php.net/mysql_error), to have some information about the error that's caused by the execution of your MySQL :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM planet1 WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$term')");
if (!$query) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}
```

*Note: of course, this echo+die is OK while developping, but should never be present on a production server.*

Comment: Thank you for this. Is `WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$term')` faster than `WHERE title LIKE '%$term%'` ?

Comment: `match` will use a fulltext index ; `like '%...%'` will scan all row of the table -- so, the first one **might** be faster.